# Multi-dimensional array access with negative index

Tags: c#

Ok, maybe I'm dumb, but Why there is no exception being thrown in the following code?

[image: code]

It's clear that the index by which the _cells array is being accessed is negative (posCol + col = -1) as shown in the picture.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't have negative indexes on an array.

Comment: @TylerDay He knows, he's asking why it doesn't throw an exception, as it should when using a negative index..

Comment: @TylerDay I know, that's the point

Comment: Sorry I misread the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely shape[row,col] is equal to 0.  If it is, C# will short circuit the rest of the conditional since it can already determine the entire thing will evaluate to false.  Since it never evaluates the second one with the negative index, it doesn't matter that posCol is negative.

Comment: After checking the code, that is indeed the cause. I'm marking your answer as correct. Thank your very much.